# How to find out what causes crashes in Windows 10 during sleep or hibernation (DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE, ntoskrnl.exe+14d220)?

Tags: windows, drivers, sleep, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

When I resume from sleep/hibernation in Windows 10, it starts normally (as it was turned off). In event log, I have found the following error:

The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000009f (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffe000b0233060, 0xffffd00035bba990, 0xffffe000abc76010). A dump was saved in: C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 081015-39234-01.

How to find out what is causing the problem, e.g. which driver? (Windows 10 was updated from Windows 8.1 where it was working ok.)

**UPDATE:**
BSOD message is this:

```
Bug Check String: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE
Bug Check Code: 0x0000009f
Parameter 1: 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2: ffffe001`2795a060
Parameter 3: ffffd001`024ab990
Parameter 4: ffffe001`33776980
Caused By Driver: ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address: ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
File Description: NT Kernel & System
Product Name: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company: Microsoft Corporation
File Version: 10.0.10240.16412 (th1.150729-1800)
Processor: x64
Crash Address: ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
```

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: @DavidPostill see the edit.

Comment: BlueScreenView is crap, share the dmp file from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: @magicandre1981, how to analyze the reason in minidump?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Minidump is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcu4nrzwv5qe61a/081015-21875-01.dmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the crash seams to be caused by the driver `btfilter.sys` (Atheros Bluetooth driver):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

    DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
    A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
    Arguments:
    Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
    Arg2: ffffe0012795a060, Physical Device Object of the stack
    Arg3: ffffd001024ab990, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
    Arg4: ffffe00133776980, The blocked IRP

    Debugging Details:
    ------------------


    SYSTEM_SKU:  PSKK6E

    SYSTEM_VERSION:  PSKK6E-02H05KCZ

    BIOS_DATE:  09/19/2014

    BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  VG10S

    BASEBOARD_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

    CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

    BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

    PROCESS_NAME:  System

    CURRENT_IRQL:  2

    ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

    STACK_TEXT:  
    00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
    01 nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
    02 nt!PopIrpWatchdog
    03 nt!KiRetireDpcList
    04 nt!KiIdleLoop


    IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16401

    FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_btfilter_IMAGE_usbhub.sys

    5: kd> !irp ffffe00133776980
    Irp is active with 15 stacks 14 is current (= 0xffffe00133776df8)
     No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
         cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context

     [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
                0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

                Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    >[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
                0 e1 ffffe0012792b030 00000000 fffff800907ecd40-ffffe0012ec4f7d0 Success Error Cancel pending
              Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\btfilter.sys, Win32 error 0n2
    *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for btfilter.sys
    *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for btfilter.sys
     \Driver\BtFilter   nt!PopSystemIrpCompletion
                Args: 00014400 00000000 00000004 00000002
     [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
                0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe0012ec4f7d0    

                Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

        Loaded symbol image file: btfilter.sys
        Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\btfilter.sys
        Image name: btfilter.sys
        Browse all global symbols  functions  data
        Timestamp:        Fri Aug 09 11:41:27 2013
```

the driver is 2 years old. Look for a driver update or remove it and look if the generic Windows driver works.

Comment: I am trying to uninstall the old driver and it seems to loop in kernel. (Uninstalling takes forever and one core is at 100 %.) Is there another save way to remove a driver that cannot be uninstalled a via device manager?

Comment: Finally after few forced powers off, I manage to disable and uninstall the driver. (Unfortunately, I was unable to start in save mode.)